# Interpolación en jade dentro de un each

Tags: javascript, html5, pug

Les quería preguntar como podría hacer para que en vez de que salga `<li><a href="#{pagina}.html">nosotros</a></li>`salga el correctamente con el nombre de la página, osea algo asi: `<li><a href="nosotros.html">nosotros</a></li>`

Mi código es el siguiente y no sé que es lo que estoy fallando:

```
-var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
ul
    each pagina in paginas
        if pagina == "inicio"
            li: a(href="/") #{pagina}
        else 
            li: a(href= "#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
```

Answer (score 1):

La interpolación en atributos ya no funciona, esa era la forma de hacerlo antes pero en la versión 2 hay otras dos formas de hacerlo.

Puedes usar la variable como se hace en javascript:

```
-var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
ul
    each pagina in paginas
        if pagina == "inicio"
            li: a(href="/") #{pagina}
        else 
            li: a(href= pagina +".html") #{pagina}
```

O puedes usar *[template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)*:

```
-var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
ul
    each pagina in paginas
        if pagina == "inicio"
            li: a(href="/") #{pagina}
        else 
            li: a(href= `${pagina}.html`) #{pagina}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que necesitas es concatenar el String con la variable `{pagina}`.

```
-var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
ul
    each pagina in paginas
        if pagina == "inicio"
            li: a(href="/") #{pagina}
        else 
            li: a(href= "#"+{pagina}+".html") #{pagina}
```